# Finding the overlap of two Bivariate Non Parametric models using R

Tags: nonparametric, bivariate, nonparametric-regression

I need a few suggestions on some methods to try or to be pointed in the right direction.
I will start off describing the big picture.
I have little stats background. I come from physics and astronomy. 
I have a map with two sets of clustered points, one of which is a test site. Visually, they look like two slightly overlapping bivariate normal distributions. Except they are not. There are anomalies in the data caused by roads, bodies of water, and places of interest that I would like to account for. 
My goal is to find the theoretical overlap between the two so that I can determine the impact a test site might have on a current site.

I would like to take out of consideration anything that I would have to arbitrarily set, like bin sizes.

I have tried the `np` package, but unless there it something I am not understanding, it seems to be over fitting (at least visually).
I also tried to fit the distribution radially, but it is not always radially symmetric, so I would rather not use that. 
I tried binning, but like I said, bin sizes are arbitrary, so no good.

I just need a few links to follow up and research if anyone has any ideas.

Thanks!

**EDIT: adding sample plots and code**

The data are in a matrix of two variables, latitude and longitude, with each lat/lon pair representing one point. The plot below is a single site:
[image: raw data]

EXAMPLE OF SITE 1
[image: heatmap of data]
EXAMPLE OF SITE 2
[image]
EXAMPLE OF THE TWO SITES WITH OVERLAP
[image]

In a nutshell, I want to know what percentage of one site is mixed with another. I have also tried Gaussian mixture modeling, but as you can tell, these forms are not ideal bi-normal distributions.

using the `np` package to try to fit a non-parametric model to a single site:

```
bw <- npudensbw(dat=site)
model <- npudens(bws=bw)
summary(model)
plot(model, xtrim = -0.2, view = "fixed", main = "")
```

Summary outputs:

```
Density Data: 2751 training points, in 2 variable(s)
                 OriginLat    OriginLon
Bandwidth(s): 0.0004860764 0.0007181774

Bandwidth Type: Fixed
Log Likelihood: 20840.14

Continuous Kernel Type: Second-Order Gaussian
No. Continuous Vars.: 2
```

Plotting outputs:

[image: np nonparametric fit]

Comment: Are you sure about the method you should use or is this assigned to you? Given the introduction, I'm not sure what you are trying to solve -- and therefore it's not clear if your choice is justified.

Comment: @cherub It is not an assignment. I don't know what method to use. I am trying to approximate a smoothed curve for each cluster and find the overlap/impact of one curve on another

Comment: can't you share some plots that describe your data?

Comment: ah! @Brunaw yes. they have been added. As you can see, there is structure caused by roads that I would like to capture in a model, but visually, the model that I have also provided looks over-fitted.

Comment: OK, thanks for putting more info in. But I still don't understand, what your goal is. You have 2D data points that have a certain distribution. Do you want to represent the specific distribution, do want to describe an "average" distribution or a special kind of distribution? Do you want to recognize other/similar point distributions as being similar or different? I'm also confused that you say that the points are distributed bi-normally, but then again they aren't.

Comment: @cherub I said that they visually look bi-normal just to paint a picture. I added more detail and more plots